# Error ao Listar Dados do Object em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, http-request

Como lista esses dados do response, principalmente o IMG, segue os dados ABAIXO:

```
  $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $objData = json_decode($data);

  $categoria = $objData->categoria->name_categoria;
  $titulo = $objData->titulo;
  $texto = $objData->texto;
  $data = $objData->data;
  $autor = $objData->autor;
  $status = $objData->status;
  $img = $objData->img->name;
```

```
{
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   autor: "Luquinhas Brito",
   categoria: {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      date_categoria: "12/04/2017",
      id_categoria: 1,
      name_categoria: "Geral",
      status_categoria: "1",
      type_categoria: "news"
   },
   data: "26/04/2017",
   img: {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      lastModifiedDate: [date] Mon Jul 18 2016 20:53:17 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil),
      name: "Capturar.JPG",
      size: 78623,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      webkitRelativePath: ""
   },
   status: "1",
   texto: "..",
   titulo: "Titulo Test"
}
```

Segue o error:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto_Sara\pages\admin\server-processing\cadastrarNews.php on line 12 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0005396592{main}( )...\index.php:0 20.0013432280router->routing( )...\index.php:69 30.03731824648require( 'C:\wamp64\www\Projeto_Sara\pages\admin\server-processing\cadastrarNews.php' )...\router.class.php:100
```

Comment: json_decode nele!11

Comment: Não lista, o img

Comment: $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $objData = json_decode($data);

  $categoria = $objData->categoria->name_categoria;
  $titulo = $objData->titulo;
  $texto = $objData->texto;
  $data = $objData->data;
  $autor = $objData->autor;
  $status = $objData->status;
  $img = $objData->img->name;

Comment: De onde você tirou esses dados em json? E como você envia para o javascript?

Comment: Uma dica: Utilize o segundo parâmetro da função json_decode($json, true), como true para que o resultado do json_decode seja um array para fácil visualização dos dados.

Answer (score 0):

Você não tem um codigo json valido, testado com [jslint](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/). 
Você pode testar com a função `echo json_last_error_msg ()`, ela devera retorna error de sintaxe. Teste assim:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);

echo json_last_error_msg ();

$categoria = $objData->categoria->name_categoria;
```

Seu json deveria possuir o formato parecido com isso:

```
{
    "img": {
        "lastModifiedDate": "[date] Mon Jul 18 2016 20:53:17 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)",
        "name": "Capturar.JPG",
        "size": 78623,
        "type": "image/jpeg",
        "webkitRelativePath": ""
    }
}
```

Você deve corrigir a codificação json, antes de enviar o conteudo para o seu php.